# Union USA states and all countries in one map chart in google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to create a map chart in Google Chart with all countries and all states in USA.
Is it possible? How can I do it?
Thanks!

```js
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700],
          // and there I want to add states to the chart
          ['Texas', 300],
          ['Ohio', 200]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: We do not code for you, we help you when you have problems in your code, so write what you already tried (if so).

Comment: @Rocky I added some code. I only added some strings into default example from google.

Comment: So just add them to the array?

Comment: No, I want to see states as countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, when you want to draw regions you must set the sesolution-option to `provinces`, but in this case it's not possible to draw countries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use custom api or something like that for create custom map-chart? Or maybe you know others analogs :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know an alternative approach